# \chemgreek + \fontspec + Lucida.otf = missing greek characters

Tags: luatex, fontspec, chemmacros, lucida

I am using `LuaLaTeX` with an Open-Type version of the Lucida font (from tug.com) along with `\chemmacros` with the latest version of TeXLive 2017. I think, that I have set up everything correctly but `\chemgreek` is missing almost every small upright greek characters. As far as I can see, the Lucida font has every character needed. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt,
               ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{all}
\chemsetup{greek = {fontspec}}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{LucidaBrightOT.otf}
\setmathfont{LucidaBrightMathOT.otf}

\begin{document}

\printchemgreekalphabet $\upalpha$ $\alpha$ \chemalpha

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the message `luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: "File not found: LucidaBrightOT.otf.".` with MikTex as well as on Cygwin (i.e. TeX Live 2017)

Comment: @albert Then you don't have the font installed (as stated in the OP it is a font that's not included in TeX distros).

Comment: @TeXnician this was not clear to me, a bit hidden in the question and I think the reference is wrong as well (should be https://www.tug.org/store/lucida/index.html). Furthermore I think it should be mentioned that the fonts are to be ordered and are not free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify how `\chemgreek_text:n` works, by choosing the math font (which has the Greek glyphs at the right positions).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usechemmodule{all}
\chemsetup{greek = {fontspec}}

\setmainfont{LucidaBrightOT.otf}
\setmathfont{LucidaBrightMathOT.otf}[NFSSFamily=lbm]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Nn \chemgreek_text:n
  { \ensuremath { \text {\fontfamily{lbm}\selectfont #1} } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printchemgreekalphabet $\upalpha$ $\alpha$ \chemalpha

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solves the problem, but I have a question about it: What does the `[NFSSFamily=lbm]` part exactly do? Is it possible that this solution messes anything else up, especially other math or unit based packages?

Comment: @Stan The option allows to use the font also as a text font, with `\fontfamily{lbm}\selectfont`. As far as I can see, `\chemgreek_text:n` is only used for processing `\chemgreek`.

Answer (score 1):

The `chemgreek` mapping `fontspec` uses the greek characters from the text font, not from the math font. Like you have seen, `LucidaBrightOT.otf` does not contain a lot of lowercase greek characters.

To use the math font instead, you need a new mapping. You could create it rom scratch, but you can also reuse the `newtx` mapping. You do not want to load `newtxmath` through, so you have to manipulate an internal variable:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{LucidaBrightOT.otf}
\setmathfont{LucidaBrightMathOT.otf}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{all}
\declarechemgreekmappingalias {unicode-math} {newtx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \prop_put:Nnn \l__chemgreek_packages_prop {unicode-math} {unicode-math}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\chemsetup{greek = {unicode-math}}

\begin{document}

\printchemgreekalphabet $\upalpha$ $\alpha$ \chemalpha

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, you are right! The text font does not have the characters only the math font. I didn't see that yesterday :)